# R: list.files returning NA instead of file name

Tags: r

I am trying to retrieve the file name for the file "cg3-chem-djtayl18PSY101.txt" which exists in my working directory using the following commands.

```
regexName = "*chem-djtayl18*.txt"
fileName <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = regexName, ignore.case = TRUE)[1] # returning NA
```

However, it is returning the file name as NA. Although it is working for 100 other files in the same directory in the same manner. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: puts dots before your stars, `.*` in regex.  It is not shell globs

Comment: yes, it worked. as soon as i posted it here i found the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Because your regex does not match the file name.

```
regexName = "*chem-djtayl18*.txt"
filename <- "cg3-chem-djtayl18PSY101.txt"
grepl(regexName, filename)
#[1] FALSE
```

Maybe you need the pattern.

```
regexName = "chem-djtayl18.*\\.txt"
grepl(regexName, filename)
#[1] TRUE
```